How to update array by gorm?
type Person struct {
    ID   int64    `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    Pets []string `gorm:"column:pets;type:ARRAY"`
}

person := Person{ID: 1}
pets := []string{"cat", "dog"}

bqStore.DB.Model(&Person{}).Create(&person)
bqStore.DB.Model(&Person{}).Where("id = ?", 1).Update("pets", pets)

The last line generates error:

failed to analyze: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Value of type STRUCT<INT64, INT64> cannot be assigned to pets, which has type ARRAY [at 1:28]

Database schema:
CREATE TABLE ` + "`project-id.dataset-id.people`" + `
(
    id INT64,
    pets ARRAY<STRING>
);

Anyone know how to make it work?

Use pq.StringArray from "github.com/lib/pq" as type for the Pets field and gorm text[] type:
type Person struct {
    ID   int64          `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    Pets pq.StringArray `gorm:"column:pets;type:text[]"`
}

pets := pq.StringArray{"cat", "dog"}


Tried and the code is hanging at bqStore.DB.Model(&Person{}).Create(&person)

What was the error ? Which DB are you using ? Did you update the table schema ?

There is no error, it just hanging at .Create. The database is Google BigQuery, not sure how to change schema?
